# Array using for loop doesn't count elements Bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, loops

I'm learning to code with bash, I want to convert a decimal number to a binary array, the problem is that I can't count the number of elements in the array.

My code is:

```
read -p 'Ingrese primer numero: ' numero_1

function binario(){
 num=$1
 arr1=()
 i=0
 while [ $num -ne 0 ]
 do
  div=$(($num/2))
  rem=$(($num%2))
  num=$div
  arr1=("$rem" "${arr1[*]}")
  echo ${arr1[*]}
 done
 echo "array 1 es ${arr1[*]}"
 echo "largo dentro de la funcion ${#arr1[*]}"
}
binario $numero_1
```

the counting does not work. In my console, I obtain this information:

```
Ingrese primer numero: 56
array 1 es 1 1 1 0 0 0
largo dentro de la funcion 1
```

I know that I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what,
Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `*` with a `@` to populate the array with the elements of the array instead of treating the whole array as one element:

```
- arr1=("$rem" "${arr1[*]}")
+ arr1=("$rem" "${arr1[@]}")
```

`*` expands to one word, `@` expands to a list of words.